# Why isn't an enum checked by the C compiler?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, enums

The following text is an excerpt from *[C Programming Language, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)*, written by the creator of the C language (so I presume it is correct):

> Although variables of enum types may be declared, compilers need not check that what you store in such a variable is a valid value for the enumeration.

I have some doubts:

1. For what cases in the C language doesn't the compiler check the value of an `enum`?
2. `enum` constants are not checked for some reason. Why not?  What are the reasons?
3. Since `enum` is not checked by the compiler, is using `enum` error-prone? Please explain.

Comment: Someone thought this was a duplicate of /questions/432937/net-why-arent-enums-range-value-checked. They probably changed their mind (the answer's the same, but the question is about a different language after all), but it's not possible to remove a close vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. An enumeration is like a fancy integer, and it's better than defining a whole load of constants or preprocessor macros as names for the constant values you want to store, because a compiler (or editor) *can* check that you're using the right names and values to go with the right type. On the other hand, being just an int, there's nothing stopping you putting in a value you didn't make a name for, which is occasionally useful.
2. They can't be checked in every case. What if you add two numbers together to get the value that's going to be put in the enum-typed variable? It could be any value, generated at runtime, so it can't be checked (without a lot of overhead, at least).
3. Everything in C is unsafe; there's practically no feature which the compiler can totally prevent you from abusing. enums are safe because they are effective at preventing programmer error and confusion, not because they stop you doing something stupid.

Comment: The other great thing about `enum`s is that some compilers warn you if you have a `switch` block that switches on an `enum`, and you leave one out of the `case` clauses.

Comment: I consider that an annoying thing about some compilers, not a great thing about `enum`. It's very possible and even likely that a certain `switch` only handles a subset of possible `enum` values by virtue of earlier logic having ruled out other values...

Comment: @R..: In that *ahem* case, you can just add `default: /* error handlign code */` to silence the warning.

Answer (score 7):

You can do a enum like

```
enum status {
    ST_READY = 1 << 0, /*  1 */
    ST_WAIT  = 1 << 1, /*  2 */
    ST_ERROR = 1 << 2, /*  4 */
    ST_HALT  = 1 << 3, /*  8 */
    ST_ETC   = 1 << 4, /* 16 */
};
```

Then define an object of that type

```
enum status status;
```

and set it to the bitwise OR of some 'simple' statuses

```
status = ST_WAIT | ST_ERROR; /* recoverable error */
```

Note that the value `ST_WAIT | ST_ERROR` is `6` and that that value is not part of the enum.

---

To answer your questions:

1. C compiler lets the programmer shoot himself in the foot.
2. C compiler lets the programmer shoot himself in the foot.
3. C compiler lets the programmer shoot himself in the foot.

Comment: +1 C just assumes you know what you are doing, and lets you get on with it in as efficient way as possible - also :g/foot/s//head/

Comment: @asc99c: I'd do that as `:%s/foot/head/g`

Comment: @pmg Can you say `1 << 0` what value this result in?

Comment: @Ant's: any value shifted left (or right) `0` bits is the initial value itself. I just use it for simmetry with the other lines.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. At what all cases in C language doesn't the compiler check the value of an enum. [edited]

When you assign to it. Assignment from bare integers is allowed, so you can do:

```
enum E { A, B } x;
x = 10000;
```

without compiler error. Also, `switch`es in enums are not check for exhaustiveness.

> 2)Why enum constants are not checked, for some reasons? What are those reasons?

People like to put integers in them. eg.

```
enum E { END_OF_EVERYTHING = 5 };
```

where 0-4 are meant as ordinary values, and 5 is kind of special.

> 3. Since enum is not checked by the compiler, using enum is error prone?

Yes. Since enums only have values of the least number of bits that can take all enum values, you can get strange results:

```
enum E { A = 1, B = -1 };
```

This enum only contains 2 bits of data (values -2, -1, 0, 1). If you assign 10000 into it, strange things may happen (actually seen).

Comment: in this code `enum E { A = 1, B = -1 };`, how could you say the values are -2,-1,0,1?